# 2x PCI-e x1 or 2x PCI-e x16?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, pci-express

I am trying to build a work PC and would like lots of screen real estate via 4 monitors and have no plans to SLI them together.  I have decided to get 2x GT 430 graphics cards which apparently need PCI-e x16 ports.  If I get a motherboard which has 2 PCI-e x1 ports, how much of the graphics cards capacity will I lose?

I will not be playing games on the PC, but will be using it for some 3d graphics, video, and audio rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will most likely go with a PCI-Ex16 since that is where most of the graphic cards interface with. You may want to look into a motherboard that has DVI and VGA integrated graphics. Something like a Core-i5 Sandy Bridge. You can put two monitors on that while getting just one video card that will drive the other two monitors.

Currently, I'm doing a similar configuration where i have an ATI Radeon HD 6970 with 3 monitors plugged into it and I have a fourth monitor on my Integrated Graphics controller (music, web browsers, nothing intensive).

They do make some PCI-Ex1 graphic adapters, but usually less common.

Comment: One thing to note. NVidia cards are limited to only 2 displays per card. ATI will allow you on their newer models to use more than two monitors (3+) using a technology called Eyefinity.

Answer (score 1):

If the graphics card has a PCI-e x16 connector, you will lose all of its capacity since you won't be able to connect it. If the graphics card has a PCI-e x1 connector, you will lose none of its capacity, because you will be connecting it to the only port it supports.

Answer (score 0):

PCIe slots have two sizes, a "physical" size and an "electrical" size. The electrical size is less than or equal to the physical size.

If the physical size of the slot is large enough for your card then you can plug it in and it will work. The bandwidth will be limited by the electrical size. If the physical size of the slot is smaller than the size of the card then you normally can't plug it in at all (there are some non-standard open back slots out there).

While you can get PCIe x1 graphics cards they are a speciality product and therefore prices are higher and choice is limited. Performance is also likely to be substantially worse though exactly how much worse will depend on the application. If the application is limited by bandwidth to the card they may be 16 times worse, OTOH if the application is limited by processing on the card and moves little data between CPU and GPU then there may be no noticable difference (for example bitcoin miners typically use x1 to hook up their cards.

There are ways to adapt a larger card to fit in a smaller slot, but they involve either destructive modifications or riser adapters that make fitting the system into a case tricky.

So in general if you want to run multiple GPUs you want to get a board with multiple slots that are x16 physical. For desktop use though it probablly doesn't matter much if one of them is only x4 electrical.